# How to display CV_32FC2 images in ROS

Tags: opencv, rviz, image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use OpenCV to calculate real-rime optical flow and display it in ROS. The task, using provided OpenCV's functionality, seems fairly easy. I've used **`uvc_camera`** and **`cv_bridge`** to capture images with ROS and convert them to **`cv::Mat`**. Then, I'm using **`calcOpticalFlowFarneback`** to calculate optical flow, which returns a **`cv::Mat`** optical flow image of type CV_32FC2.

The code I'm using to publish the image looks like this:

```
cv_bridge::CvImage flowImage;
sensor_msgs::ImagePtr flowImagePtr;

if (!_flow.empty()) {
  flowImage.header = cvImagePtr_->header; //copy header from input image
  flowImage.encoding = sensor_msgs::image_encodings::TYPE_32FC2;
  flowImage.image = _flow; //_flow is calculated elsewhere

  flowImagePtr = flowImage.toImageMsg();
  publishCvImage(flowImagePtr); //uses a publisher to publish image
}
```

The code works fine, but ROS is unable to display floating point images (I tried either image_view and rviz). What is the right way to convert those images to a displayable form?

Cheers, Tom.

**Edit:**
Eventually I'm using these two methods to visualize the results (the below code bases on [this](http://code.google.com/p/tactical-visual-servoing/source/browse/tracking_algorithms/Optical_Flow/Farneback/Farneback.cpp?spec=svn497d76fd8bfc331574ebf751b0fb6a7b4bb6cf90&r=497d76fd8bfc331574ebf751b0fb6a7b4bb6cf90)):

```
cvImagePtr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(image, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::RGB8);
    flowImage = cvImagePtr->image; //original RGB captured image, needs to be converted to MONO8 for cv::calcOpticalFlowFarneback
cv::Mat velx = cv::Mat(flowImage.size(), CV_32FC1);
cv::Mat vely = cv::Mat(flowImage.size(), CV_32FC1);
cv::Mat flowMatrix; //outcome of cv::calcOpticalFlowFarneback

void OpticalFlow::extractFlowFieldFarneback() {

    for (int row = 0; row < flowMatrix.rows; row++) {
        float *vx = (float*)(velx.data + velx.step * row);
        float *vy = (float*)(vely.data + vely.step * row);

        const float* f = (const float*)(flowMatrix.data + flowMatrix.step * row);
        for (int col = 0; col < flowMatrix.cols; col++) {
            vx[col] = f[2*col];
            vy[col] = f[2*col+1];
        }
    }
}

void OpticalFlow::overlayFlowFieldFarneback() {

    if (!velx.empty() && !vely.empty()) {

        for (int row = 0; row < flowImage.rows; row++) {
            float *vx = (float*)(velx.data + velx.step * row);
            float *vy = (float*)(vely.data + vely.step * row);

            for (int col = 0; col < flowImage.cols; col++) {
                double length = sqrt(vx[col]*vx[col] + vy[col]*vy[col]);

                if (length > 1) {
                    cv::Point2i p1(col, row);
                    cv::Point2i p2(col + (int)vx[col], row + (int)vy[col]);

                    cv::line(flowImage, p1, p2, cvScalar(255, 0, 0, 0));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10067/how-to-display-cv_32fc2-images-in-ros/) by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1079 on 2011-05-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you just want to visually inspect it, you could scale the value range according to the maximum value:

```
00436 void depthToCV8UC1(const cv::Mat& float_img, cv::Mat& mono8_img){
00437   //Process images
00438   if(mono8_img.rows != float_img.rows || mono8_img.cols != float_img.cols){
00439     mono8_img = cv::Mat(float_img.size(), CV_8UC1);}
00440   //The following doesn't work if there are NaNs
00441   double minVal, maxVal; 
00442   minMaxLoc(float_img, &minVal, &maxVal);
00443   ROS_DEBUG("Minimum/Maximum Depth in current image: %f/%f", minVal, maxVal);
00446   cv::convertScaleAbs(float_img, mono8_img, 100, 0.0);
00447 }
```

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-05-25**:
Ah, that is because you have channels for x and y. I don't know any simple way to get that visualized, sorry

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-05-25**:
Thanks Felix, the idea is ok, but I get the error: OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (img.channels() == 1) in minMaxLoc. What I'd like to achieve the most, is to obtain nice real-time images with arrows showing temporary optical-flow vectors overlayed over the image - is there a simple way?